# Is there a verb meaning 'to fail to discern analogies between things'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'was looking for a verb meaning 'to fail to discern **analogies** between things', but, after a bit of searching, I realized that 'confound', which first came to my mind, is not the right term because Merriam-Webster defines it as 'to fail to discern **differences** between' things, not **analogies**.

Thus, my question is, is there a verb meaning 'to fail to discern **analogies** between things'?

Comment: Nothing specific, beyond obvious catch-all terms like *dull*, *obtuse*, *thick*, etc.

Comment: @Robusto, but, afaik, those verbs means 'to fail to discern **both** differences **and** analogies between things', whereas I want a verb strictly related, and possibly only related, with *analogies*.

Comment: I’m having trouble even imagining what such a character trait would _be_ in practice. Do you mean someone who does not see (without being told, at least) that there is a high degree of similarity between the stories in _West Side Story_, _Romeo and Juliet_, and _Pyramus and Thisbe_, for example? You could make up a joking, PC term like ***similarly challenged***, though I guess not many would understand what you meant.

Comment: I would call such a person _overly literal._

Comment: He can't see the forest for the trees. (he misses the overall pattern because he's lost in meaningless detail).

Answer (score 3):

Not a verb, but how about *pattern blindness*?

Comment: This is a fascinating answer that is on the trail of an elusive quarry, and it has some merit. It just feels a shade shy of the bull's-eye for me.

Comment: Nice expression!

Answer (score 2):

People who are good at analogies are good at "connecting the dots."

So the term I would use is "unable to connect the dots."

Comment: Your first statement is at best a stretch. Your second leaps into the void.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say, if anything, your closest bet would be *dissociate* (also written as *disassociate*).

Comment: This has no such specific association.

Comment: @Robusto Yes it doesn't, can't it? It's the President of the Association of United Individualists.

Answer (score 0):

A person who is failing to make connections can be described as ***being obtuse***. This can be used to describe someone who is failing to do so despite their best efforts (e.g. "Forgive me for being obtuse, but can you repeat that?"), but I consider it especially apt for describing someone who isn't really trying to understand or is resistant to the idea in some way (in somewhat the same sense that Upton Sinclair meant when he wrote, "It is difficult to get a man to understand something, when his salary depends upon his not understanding it.").

"Being obtuse" can also be used to describe someone who does understand but is being overly pedantic, as in:

```
Alice: "Can you hand me one of those Kleenex?"
Bob (not moving): "Those aren't Kleenex-brand, they're generic facial tissues."
Alice: "Oh, don't be so obtuse."
```